# Read an ".sbt like" file for highly customizable configurations in Scala

Tags: scala, sbt

I'd like to write a simple app to crawl/scrape some web content. The more I delve into the analysis, the more I realize that the instructions I need to give to the app in order to navigate through the site and get the content I wish it to extract, may be very peculiar depending on the target website structure.

The idea was to write some configuration files to define how the app should browse and scrape each specific site, but defining such behaviour could be challenging, unless you write in the configuration file some actual Scala code.

So, the idea is to write some code able to get a scraper object instance reading a file written in the .sbt format and inject some code in it.

First of all, I need to know where to start to achieve such task: **what library should I use?**

**Could it be easier to write some sbt tasks and use sbt as the core of the app instead of writing one from scratch?** What should be the limitations in this approach?

I apologize for being so general, but I don't have the slightest idea from where to start. I'd like you to head me to the right direction and post some docs to read.

Consider the app is meant to be a CLI tool, no graphical interface needed, then.

Comment: sbt, being a build tool, is probably not the tool I would use for any of this (barring the actual build of the software)

Comment: If you're interested in a domain-specific language in configuration files, you could use the [parser-combinator library](https://github.com/scala/scala-parser-combinators) to build one. If you're interested in pure Scala, you should simply write a Scala-based DSL instead.

Comment: "Which library should I use" is OT for SO. But I don't quite understand the issue; this sounds more like a DSL than anything else.

Comment: Is it the actual dsl or the task engine part of sbt you would want to use? How does the dsl apply to your problem? It is mostly designed to apply settings